# Changing the time from one format to Local time in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, datetime, express

I am getting a response in this format "2018-02-09T09:30:00.000Z" while using ews-javascript-api module in Node.js. Need to change it to local time (or) "2018-2-9 15:00:00" (or) "Tue Feb 09 2018 15:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)" using Javascript. Can anyone help?

Comment: JavaScript is not Java.

Comment: I am using Javascript, can you solve this issue in JS?